# Check for broken image

Tags: php, image

Check for broken images, how can i check that image is available on given location or not ?

When the given image is available then only i have to display an image otherwise not.

### For example :

1) The below image is not broken

```
<img width="56" height="56" alt="801 - 2 Bedroom Cabin" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/highlandscondos/7/801 Bath 2.jpg" class="rsTmb">
```

2) The below image is broken

```
<img width="56" height="56" alt="801 - 2 Bedroom Cabin" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/highlandscondos/7/801 LR 2.jpg" class="rsTmb">
```

In the above two cases It display like

[image]

I don't want to display broken image.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: First, note that spaces in URIs are not allowed, you must URL-encode them as `%20` (or `+` in query-strings). Also check the filename is case-sensitive. This question doesn't have anything to do with PHP unless you're interested in checking the existence of the file server-side. If the file was local to the website than you can easily do it with `file_exists`, but as it's hosted on Amazon you'd have to use cURL (or another HTTP library) which drastically slow-down your page generation times (especially as PHP is single-threaded).

Comment: @Dai I need the way to check for the image from PHP side because the image is coming from 3rd party. So, i need to check at PHP end that image is available or not. And if available then only that image is display.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you could try what's [described at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/better-broken-image-handling/). However, some people replying there said in the comments that it doesn't work in IE.

```js
// Replace source
$('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/YnsUsfk.png#nopictureavailable.png');
});

// Or, hide them
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img width="56" height="56" alt="801 - 2 Bedroom Cabin" src="https://i.imgur.com/FQFzBJh.png" class="rsTmb">
<img width="56" height="56" alt="801 - 2 Bedroom Cabin" src="https://example.com/404" class="rsTmb">
```